# Chroma-Filtering video using GPUImage?

Tags: ios, video, transparency, gpuimage

I am attempting to display a video file with transparency inside my application using a transparency key (`RGB: 0x00FF00`, or full green) using @BradLarson's awesome [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) toolkit. However, I am experiencing some difficulties with the `GPUImageChromaKeyFilter` filter, and I don't quite understand why.

My source video file is available in my dropbox [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25258177/personal/sample.m4v) (12 KB, 3 seconds long, full green background, just a square on the screen),

And I used the sample project titled `SimpleVideoFilter`.

This is the code I attempted to use (I simply replaced `-viewDidLoad`):

```
NSURL *sampleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample" withExtension:@"m4v"];
movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:sampleURL];

filter = [[GPUImageChromaKeyFilter alloc] init];
[filter setColorToReplaceRed:0 green:1 blue:0];
[filter setEnabled:YES];

[movieFile addTarget:filter];

GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
[filter addTarget:filterView];

[movieFile startProcessing];
```

According to the documentation (which is sparse), this *should* have the effect of replacing all of the green in the video. Instead, I get this as an output:

[image: Screenshot of video]

Which tells me that the video is playing (and thus it's  copying to the application), but it doesn't seem to be doing any chroma keying. Why would this be? Do I need to manually set smoothing values & thresholds? I shouldn't, because the source only contains two colors (`0x00FF00` and `0x000000`).

I have tested this on the device as well, to no avail. Almost all other filters I attempt to use work, such as `GPUImageRGBFilter`, `GPUImageSepiaFilter`, etc. Could `GPUImageChromaKeyFilter` just be broken?

Any help with this would be appreciated, as at this point I'm scraping the bottom of the barrel for transparency on a video.

Comment: @BradLarson I'd love to see some input from you on this.

Comment: Hi Richard, did you manage to solve the issue? Would you post the code ? Thanks :D

Comment: nope; didn't fix it ;( I was hoping @BradLarson could come in here and answer himself, but alas that isn't the case.

Comment: So, I ran into the same problem and was not able to get it working. But after emailing Brad, I found that a workaround did in fact solve the problem as far as having a view be non-opaque goes. Source code for an example app is provided in this blog post on the subject: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post18_green_screen/index.html

Answer (score 9):

Similar to the original question, I wanted to put a green-screen video on top of a custom view hierarchy incl. live video. Turned out this was not possible with the standard GPUImage ChromaKey filter(s). Instead of alpha blending, it blended the green pixels with the background pixels. For example a red background became yellow and blue became cyan.

The way to get it working involves two steps:

**1) make sure the filterview has a transparent background:**

```
filterView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

**2) Modify GPUImageChromaKeyFilter.m**

```
old: gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb, textureColor.a * blendValue);
new: gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb * blendValue, 1.0 * blendValue);
```

Now all keyed (for example green) pixels in the video become transparent and uncover whatever is below the filterview, incl. (live-)video.

Comment: This is actually very similar to what I ended up doing, but mine ended up changing the OpenGL layer & writing a custom filter. +1

Comment: I wanted to do the same thing. Playing transparent video on the camera layer. Can you please tell me how did you do it?

This example works with the two video. But I wanted to add it to the camera layer as a live feed 
https://github.com/tuo/GPUImage/tree/master/examples/iOS/ChromaKeyVideoMerge

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by using **GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter** and setting a background image. I'd like to know though if we can do without having to set a background. When I don't set the background, the movie shows as white, but adding the background renders fine...

```
filter = [[GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter alloc] init];
[(GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter *)filter setColorToReplaceRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0];
[(GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter *)filter setThresholdSensitivity:0.4];

UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
[sourcePicture addTarget:filter];
[sourcePicture processImage];
```

Comment: So is `background.png` a transparent image? Or the image of the superview?

Comment: I just tested with a transparent image: http://imgur.com/jWaOW. That won't do what I need, it **absolutely** must be transparent for the background of the video, unfortunately.

Comment: It was just a plain image actually, here's the project I used which worked for me:  http://ge.tt/29kBY5R

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't make the GPUImageView transparent, which is what I needed.

Comment: Then I had misunderstood the initial question, sorry!

Comment: any news on this Richard? got the same problem.

Comment: @user375584, It actually works with the transparent image. But you have to set the GPUImageView background to transparent as well.