# GPUImage Chroma Key filter

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, gpuimage

I am trying to use the GPUImage framework's chromakey filter. I followed the Filtershowcase example, but obviously I am missed something becuase it only shows the video, but no green screen keying out effect. Here's my initialization of video camera/filter:

```
camera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480
                                             cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
camera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
camera.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = NO;
camera.horizontallyMirrorRearFacingCamera = NO;


chromaKeyFilter = [[GPUImageChromaKeyFilter alloc] init];
chromaKeyFilter.thresholdSensitivity = sliderThres.value;

UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WID-small.jpg"];


GPUImagePicture *sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage
                                                    smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];


[camera addTarget:chromaKeyFilter];
[sourcePicture addTarget:chromaKeyFilter];
[sourcePicture processImage];

[chromaKeyFilter addTarget:viewCamera];


[camera startCameraCapture];
```

So camera and sourcePicture both feed into the filter, filter than goes into viewCamera. But right now, I only see the plain video, no chromakey effect. (I have a slider that alters the threshold).

**UPDATED** with GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter

```
camera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
camera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
chromaKeyFilter = [[GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter alloc] init];


UIImage *inputImage;
inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WID-small.jpg"];
GPUImagePicture *sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];


[camera addTarget:chromaKeyFilter];
[sourcePicture processImage];
[sourcePicture addTarget:chromaKeyFilter];
[chromaKeyFilter addTarget:viewCamera];

[camera startCameraCapture];
```

With this filter, it simply replaced it with black, not the actual image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Found this gem after a couple of days of trying....](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/597#issuecomment-9949345). Apparently you are suppose to hang on (strong ref) to GPUImagePicture. I was under the impression that the filter chain internally would have a strong reference, but that's not the case. Keeping it as instance var solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter, not the GPUImageChromaKeyFilter.

The blend takes in two source images, and replaces pixels matching the keying color in the first image with the pixel from the second image. The regular chroma keying filter simply reduces the alpha channel of pixels matching the target color to 0.0, it doesn't blend in another image.

Comment: Thanks, I did that. But now it replaces the green with black, rather than the image. I've updated the code. I think I am doing something wrong with the pipeline...

Comment: @0xSina - Are you sure that the WID-small.jpg is being properly copied into your application's bundle as a resource? If so, also try moving the `[sourcePicture processImage];` line after all targets have been added.

Comment: Yes, I NSLog the UIImage and it prints '<UIImage: 0x1f881260>'. I tried placing it after all targets, but still it won't show the image. Just black for keyed out areas. It's strange because I am doing exactly what you are doing in FilterShowcase and it works there, but not in my project...

Comment: Found out what's wrong (after trying for two days) from a comment of yours on github. Thanks!

Comment: Needed to keep strong reference to GPUImagePicture. I am not familiar with the internals, but why doesn't the filter chain keep a strong ref to it?

Comment: @0xSina - Why should it? As an input, it's the application's responsibility to keep a hold of it. If the framework kept a strong reference to (or retained) the inputs, that would cause a retain cycle and lead to many, many memory leaks. Things downstream are retained by those upstream, but sources of data need to be retained by the application in order for them to stick around.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the original question, I wanted to put a green-screen video on top of a custom view hierarchy incl. live video. Turned out this was not possible with the standard GPUImage ChromaKey filter(s). Instead of alpha blending, it blended the green pixels with the background pixels. For example a red background became yellow and blue became cyan.

The way to get it working involves two steps:

**1) make sure the filterview has a transparent background:**

```
filterView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

**2) Modify GPUImageChromaKeyFilter.m**

```
old: gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb, textureColor.a * blendValue);

new: gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb * blendValue, 1.0 * blendValue);
```

Now all keyed (for example green) pixels in the video become transparent and uncover whatever is below the filterview, incl. (live-)video.

Comment: Actually, this was the question that had a similar problem.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462805/chroma-filtering-video-using-gpuimage/16169412#16169412

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the target and selector for the slider?

This worked for me

```
[(GPUImageChromaKeyFilter *)filter setThresholdSensitivity:[(UISlider *)sender value]];
        [image setImage:[filter imageByFilteringImage:sourceImage]];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, but settings the threshold doesn't have anything to do with it anyways even if i didnt as the default is 0.4