# Play video using GPUimage

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, avfoundation, gpuimage

In my app I have to play an alpha channel video as an overlay over the current view (I'm planning to achieve this alpha channel video using GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter or GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter), so I wanted to know if the output video after applying these filters can be played using **GPUImage**? If we can, then can I get some sample code for the same.

I know **AVAnimator** is an option but I want to apply filters to these overlay videos i.e.brightness,saturation etc which has to be visible while video is being played because of which I can't use AVAnimator. But this being the next step for now I want to know how to play video using GPUImage.

Thanks in advance! :]

Answer (score 0):

Well, even though I like telling people about AVAnimator, Brad Larson's GPUImage is specifically designed to be a GPU based filtering framework for iOS apps. Application of real time effects like the ones you describe is exactly what GPUImage was designed for. See [GPUImage Chroma Key filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459607/gpuimage-chroma-key-filter)

Comment: Thanks MoDJ, I'm actually using AVAnimator now to play Alpha channel videos without applying any filter, BTW Its a great framework!!! One question I had is will setting Architecture in Build Settings to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) create any problem while releasing the app to appstore (as its required for AVAnimator)? Please let me know about it.

Comment: Grab the current version on github so that you can set the flag to build both 32 and 64 bit versions of the binary.

Comment: I'm using the current version from github, and when I set the Architecture to **$(ARCHS_STANDARD)** my app is crashing and giving me the following error :


_frameDecoder openForReading "FightersMaxVid.mvid"
*** Assertion failure in -[AVMvidFrameDecoder advanceToFrame:], /ProjectDirPath/ExternalFrameworks/AVAnimatorFramework/AVAnimator/AVMvidFrameDecoder.m:844
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'framebuffer num bytes'_
Could you please tell me how to avoid it?

Comment: Could you just email me directly, this discussion is not really related to the original SO question and this just looks like a configuration issue with your xcode project.

Comment: Just an FYI, but I just published a blog post that goes into detail on how the green screen approach used in GPUImage compares to the alpha channel approach here: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post18_green_screen/index.html